# UI image is instantiating in wrong position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to instansiate a line where i click in the screen, the origin of the line is where i first clicked and the end of the line is where the mouse is at the moment all this happens while the mouse button is down. The problem is that i give give the origin of the line the exact same value of the mouse in that moment but is been instansiated with a offset and i dont understand why because im doing some prints of the transform.position of the line origin and of the mouse and both match.

The script is in the panel and he es contained by the canvas, the canvas Render mode is World Space.

Heres an Screenshoot where it shows exactly where i click and where it instansiates.

[image]

**CODE:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mousePos;
    public Camera cam;
    public GameObject dirLine;
    public Vector2 origin;

    GameObject tempLine;
    Vector2 ending;
    Vector2 dir;
    float width;
    bool spawned;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cam = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        spawned = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition);
        if (tempLine != null)
        {

            ending = Input.mousePosition;

            dir = ending - origin;
            width = dir.magnitude;
            //tempLine.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = origin;
            tempLine.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(width, tempLine.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y);
            float angle = Vector2.SignedAngle(dir, Vector2.up);
            tempLine.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -(angle - 90));
            Debug.Log("LocalPosition de la linea:"+tempLine.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition);
        }
    }
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        spawned = true;
        Vector3 screenpoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 1.0f);
        //origin = GameObject.Find("Panel").transform.localPosition;
        tempLine = Instantiate(dirLine,transform);
        origin = screenpoint;
        tempLine.transform.localPosition = origin;
        tempLine.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = origin;
        Debug.Log("Posicion del Mouse al ser clicado"+Input.mousePosition);
    }
    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        spawned = false;
        Destroy(tempLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: the screenshot shows the click and the instantiate happening at the same spot - so, why are you moving the localposition of the object after - what are you expecting this to achieve if not moving it away from where you clicked.  Did you not mean to just move the position of the tempLine item you made?

Comment: PS note as you are changing localpostition not position its effected by the fact your scale is 0.3 ....

Comment: I think your problem is that you are setting the local position.  The position you instantiate it with is the position in the world space.... The you use those coordinates to set the localPosition which is the position relative to the container or parent.

Comment: By the way you are NOT printing the position... You are printing the localPosition which is not the same thing.  The mouse position is not LOCAL.  So even though it matches the values the point of origin is different.

Comment: @BugFinder im trying to achive the effect in the link . basically where ever you click that will be your origin point and the line should instantsiate there no with this offset that is happening to me. [linkToTheImage](https://imgur.com/a/0q6s9nj). Also the scale of the canvas is automatically resized as he is child of the camera cause the camera follow the player. still dont understand why it has that offset, also i just tried changing localPosition to postion and instantsiates the lines like in russia haha.

Comment: @BugFinder Also i just tried removing this 2 lines.  `tempLine.transform.localPosition = origin;`
 ` tempLine.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = origin;`                                  And the lines are placed in the left cent of the panel by default, dont know why

Comment: By the way you can simplify your instantiation to just say tempLine = Instantiate(dirLine,screenpoint,Quaternion.identity ); and remove  tempLine.transform.localPosition = origin;
        tempLine.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = origin;

Comment: What is the position of the panel?

Comment: Also can you print the position of the tempLine instead of the localPosition?

Comment: I think the key here is to quit using localposition, you seem to want to use the position in the world.